# Jenkins does not build branch after merging with another one

Tags: git, merge, jenkins, gitlab

I have a **Jenkins** job that builds all **Git** branches of some project. This job is triggered with push notification from **GitLab**. Everything works fine except for one problem. When I merge one branch into another:

`git merge development some-feature`

**Jenkins** does not build `development` branch because in most cases after the merge both `development` and `some-feature` point to the same commit and **Jenkins** already built this commit within `some-feature` branch.

Is there any way to work around this? I really need to build `development` in this case, because I would like developers (and testers) be able to get **latest** `development` build.

P.S. The same applies for other long-living branches we use (e.g. `master`).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this seems like a know problem, and a solution would be to create a separate project for your main branch or provide a fix :)

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9756
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17411

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me...

[http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ljgv/setup-github-and-jenkins-integration-for-pull-request-builder-and-merger]

make sure -

1. Type origin/master in "Branch Specifier" field
2. Just the push event on your webhook creation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).